# Compute C's `%` using Python's `%`?

Tags: python, c, modulus

How do I compute C's `%` using Python's `%`?
The difference between the two is in the way they handle the case of negative arguments.

In both languages, the `%` is defined in such a way that this relationship (`//` being integer division) holds:

```py
a // b * b + a % b == a
```

but the rounding of `a // b` is different in C and in Python, leading to a different definition of `a % b`.

For example, in C (where integer division is just `/` with `int` operands) we have:

```c
int a = 31;
int b = -3;
a / b;  // -10
a % b;  // 1
```

while in Python:

```py
a = 31
b = -3
a // b  # -11
a % b  # -2
```

I am aware of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1907565/5218354), which addresses the opposite (i.e. how to compute Python's `%` from C's `%`) and contains additional discussions.

I am also aware of Python 3.7 `math` module introducing [`remainder()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/math.html#math.remainder) but its result is a `float`, not an `int` and hence it will not enjoy arbitrary precision.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some ways would be:

```py
def mod_c0(a, b):
    if b < 0:
        b = -b
    return -1 * (-a % b) if a < 0 else a % b
```

```py
def mod_c1(a, b):
    return (-1 if a < 0 else 1) * ((a if a > 0 else -a) % (b if b > 0 else -b))
```

```py
def mod_c2(a, b):
    return (-1 if a < 0 else 1) * (abs(a) % abs(b))
```

```py
def mod_c3(a, b):
    r = a % b
    return (r - b) if (a < 0) != (b < 0) and r != 0 else r
```

```py
def mod_c4(a, b):
    r = a % b
    return (r - b) if (a * b < 0) and r != 0 else r
```

```py
def mod_c5(a, b):
    return a % (-b if a ^ b < 0 else b)
```

```py
def mod_c6(a, b):
    a_xor_b = a ^ b
    n = a_xor_b.bit_length()
    x = a_xor_b >> n
    return a % (b * (x | 1))
```

```py
def mod_c7(a, b):
    a_xor_b = a ^ b
    n = a_xor_b.bit_length()
    x = a_xor_b >> n
    return a % ((-b & x) | (b & ~x))
```

```py
def mod_c8(a, b):
    q, r = divmod(a, b)
    if (a >= 0) != (b >= 0) and r:
        q += 1
    return a - q * b
```

```py
def mod_c9(a, b):
    if a >= 0:
        if b >= 0:
            return a % b
        else:
            return a % -b
    else:
        if b >= 0:
            return -(-a % b)
        else:
            return a % b
```

which all work as expected, e.g.:

```py
print(mod_c0(31, -3))
# 1
```

Essentially, `mod_c0()` implements an optimized version of `mod_c1()` and `mod_c2()`, which are identical except that in `mod_c1()` the call to (relatively expensive) call to `abs()` is replaced by a ternary conditional operator with the same semantic.
Instead, `mod_c3()` and `mod_c4()` try to directly fix the `a % b` value for the cases where it is needed. The difference between the two is in how they detect opposite signs of the arguments: `(a < 0) != (b != 0)` versus `a * b < 0`.
The `mod_c5()` approach is inspired by [@ArborealAnole's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61370151/5218354), and essentially uses the bit-wise xor to handle the cases correctly, while `mod_c6()` and `mod_c7()` are the same as [@ArborealAnole's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61370151/5218354) but using adaptive right shift with `int.bit_length()`.
The `mod_c8()` approach uses a corrected definition of integer division to fix up the modulus value.
The `mod_c9()` method is inspired by [@NeverGoodEnough's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61385687/5218354), and essentially goes full conditional.

---

Covering all sign cases:

```py
vals = (3, -3, 31, -31)
s = '{:<{n}}' * 4
n = 14
print(s.format('a', 'b', 'mod(a, b)', 'mod_c(a, b)', n=n))
print(s.format(*(('-' * (n - 1),) * 4), n=n))
for a, b in itertools.product(vals, repeat=2):
    print(s.format(a, b, mod(a, b), mod_c0(a, b), n=n))
```

```
a             b             mod(a, b)     mod_c(a, b)   
------------- ------------- ------------- ------------- 
3             3             0             0             
3             -3            0             0             
3             31            3             3             
3             -31           -28           3             
-3            3             0             0             
-3            -3            0             0             
-3            31            28            -3            
-3            -31           -3            -3            
31            3             1             1             
31            -3            -2            1             
31            31            0             0             
31            -31           0             0             
-31           3             2             -1            
-31           -3            -1            -1            
-31           31            0             0             
-31           -31           0             0
```

---

A bit more tests and benchmarks:

```py
import itertools


n = 100
l = [x for x in range(-n, n + 1)]
ll = [(a, b) for a, b in itertools.product(l, repeat=2) if b]


funcs = mod_c0, mod_c1, mod_c2, mod_c3, mod_c4, mod_c5, mod_c6, mod_c7, mod_c8, mod_c9
for func in funcs:
    correct = all(func(a, b) == funcs[0](a, b) for a, b in ll)
    print(f"{func.__name__}  correct:{correct}  ", end="")
    %timeit -n 8 -r 8 [func(a, b) for a, b in ll]
# mod_c0  correct:True  8 loops, best of 8: 9.67 ms per loop
# mod_c1  correct:True  8 loops, best of 8: 11.1 ms per loop
# mod_c2  correct:True  8 loops, best of 8: 12.3 ms per loop
# mod_c3  correct:True  8 loops, best of 8: 10.3 ms per loop
# mod_c4  correct:True  8 loops, best of 8: 10 ms per loop
# mod_c5  correct:True  8 loops, best of 8: 10.1 ms per loop
# mod_c6  correct:True  8 loops, best of 8: 17.1 ms per loop
# mod_c7  correct:True  8 loops, best of 8: 20.3 ms per loop
# mod_c8  correct:True  8 loops, best of 8: 15.8 ms per loop
# mod_c9  correct:True  8 loops, best of 8: 9.29 ms per loop
```

---

Perhaps there are better (shorter?, faster?) ways, given that the implementation of Python's `%` using C's `%` seems much simpler:

```c
((a % b) + b) % b
```

---

To get some feeling on how the C-style `%` computation (`mod_c*()` functions from above) stands against the usual `%` or the operations required to get Python-style `%` from `C`:

```py
def mod_py(a, b):
    return a % b

def mod_c2py(a, b):
    return ((a % b) + b) % b


%timeit [mod_py(a, b) for a, b in ll]
# 100 loops, best of 3: 5.85 ms per loop
%timeit [mod_c2py(a, b) for a, b in ll]
# 100 loops, best of 3: 7.84 ms per loop
```

Note of course that `mod_c2py()` is only useful to get a feeling of what performances we could expect from a `mod_c()` function.

---

(**EDITED** to fix some of the proposed methods and include some timings)

(**EDITED-2** to add the `mod_c5()` solution)

(**EDITED-3** to add the `mod_c6()` to `mod_c9()` solutions)

Answer (score 3):

I am following up the very comprehensive answer of @norok2.
I have tried the super-naive approach with branches, and it appears to be slightly but consistently faster (~2-4%).

```
def mod_naive(x,y):
  if y < 0:
    if x < 0:
      return x%y
    else:
      return (x%-y)
  else:
    if x < 0:
      return -(-x%y)
    else:
      return x%y
```

or with a lambda (does not affect speed, only coolness):

```
mod_naive = lambda x,y: (x%y if x < 0 else x%-y) if y < 0 else (-(-x%y) if x < 0 else x%y)
```

Compared to @norok2's fastest solution (`mod_c0`):

> ```
> mod_c0 correct: True
> 100 loops, best of 3: 6.86 ms per loop
>
> mod_naive correct: True
> 100 loops, best of 3: 6.58 ms per loop
> ```

My (naive) guess on the reason why is that the branch prediction algorithms will eventually produce less operations overall.

Answer (score 1):

For 64-bit integers, either of these should work:

```
def mod_c_AA0(a,b):
    x=(a^b)>>63
    return a % (b*(x|1))
```

```
def mod_c_AA1(a,b):
    x=(a^b)>>63
    return a % ((-b & x)|(b & ~x))
```

using two's complement binary. As norok2 suggests, substitute `a_xor_b=a^b; x=a_xor_b>>a_xor_b.bit_length();` for the first line to have optimal specificity on bit shifting depending on the magnitude of `a` and `b`.

Comment: You can replace the hard-coded numbers with appropriate calls to `bit_length()`, e.g. `def mod_c_xor(a, b): a_xor_b = a ^ b; x = a_xor_b >> a_xor_b.bit_length(); return a % (b * (x | 1))`.

Comment: also, then `k & ...` becomes superfluous.

Comment: finally: `b * (x|1)` can become simply: `-b if a ^ b < 0 else b`

Comment: Whoops, nice catch on `k`. I kept it as `b * (x|1)` because I wanted to avoid conditionals. But that's also a good solution.